# PyQt: wait until window is visible

Tags: pyqt4

I do run some time consuming calculations and want to show a splash screen while the process is running. I've tried:

```
form = QSpashScreen()
form.showMessage('Please wait ...')
form.show()
time_consuming_function()
form.close()
```

But the splash screen doesn't actually appear. How can I make this work?

Comment: The reason that the splash screen doesn't turn up is that the tread is blocked by the "time_consuming_function". And when the function returns the form is closed before ever have being mapped. One way is to try to move the "time_consuming_function" into another thread (I'm not sure that this will work, since it involves plotting).

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify one parent for QSplashScreen, otherwise it will map the constructor of this in native Qt:

```
QSplashScreen::QSplashScreen ( const QPixmap & pixmap = QPixmap(), Qt::WindowFlags f = 0 )
Construct a splash screen that will display the pixmap.

There should be no need to set the widget flags, f, except perhaps Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint.
```

If you don't have a parent widget for this, you can assign the QDesktopWidget as the parent

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import time


def time_consuming_function():
    time.sleep(10)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = QSplashScreen(QDesktopWidget().screen())
    form.showMessage('Please wait ...')
    form.resize(1000, 1000)
    form.move(0, 0)
    form.show()
    time_consuming_function()
    form.close()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    main()
```

By the way, you should not use the "tiem_consuming_function" with the same thread of main, this will block the UI thread, make the UI thread unable to respond the user input, looks like the UI is freezing.

Comment: The "btw" remark is the actual problem. That's also the reason why I do the splash screen in the first place. The widget is never actually shown, since the "time_consuming_function" is blocking the main thread. The "time_consuming_function" involves plotting into a matplotlib canvas and that's why it is not so straight forward to put it into another thread

Comment: You  can try the code, it should show, but the UI is not responding since I put it in the UI thread.

Comment: It might show in some cases, but there is no guarantee. I've tried it wit a simple widget containing just a label. The widget itself turned up, but the label text never appeared.

Comment: I set the parent widget to QDesktopWidget, so you need to minimize all other window, then it should be visible.